# Power Steering issue

Tags: dodge, power-steering, durango

I just had the ac compressor replaced on my 2003 Dodge Durango and now the power steering intermittently is stiff.  I was told it needed power steering fluid so I added some but that didn't work.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Can you tell if there is any liquids on the serpentine belt? If oil or even power steering fluid were to be on the belt, you'd feel stiff spots in your steering. This would be due to the belt slipping.

Comment: Interesting, no I didn't but I will look.  Will that eventually wear off or will I have to replace the serpentine belt?

Comment: It will - eventually - wear off. Perhaps some kind of solvent (like brake cleaner) would help. I don't know if it's recommended to use that on belts.